# Bash expansion does not work in popen

Tags: c, bash, popen

I have a large collection of files from `file1.txt` to `file1000000.txt` all stored in folder `files`. I need to copy a range of files in command line to folder `filesCopy`. I use bash expansion as follows and everything works just fine:

```
cp files/file{100..102}.txt filesCopy
```

But, using the same command through popen gives me error.

```
FILE* pipe = popen("cp files/file{100..102}.txt filesCopy", "r");

if (!pipe)
    throw("ERROR!");
char buffer[128];
string result = "";
while(!feof(pipe)) 
{
    if(fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
        result += buffer;
}
pclose(pipe);
```

What can be wrong here?
Is it possible that bash expansion does not work through piping?

What is a solution here?

Comment: I doubt your piped process is using bash as the shell.

Comment: `ls -l /bin/sh` please.

Comment: @hobbs Oh! /bin/sh is a symbolic link to dash

Comment: Even if it were a symlink to Bash, it would not work. Most Bash-only features are disabled when you invoke Bash as `sh`. Also, some features are only available in interactive shells (`bash -i`) ... but brace globs is not one of them.

Comment: This also begs the question, what are you actually trying to accomplish, and is C a good platform for that? There was a time when this sort of unholy marriage between shell and C was a necessity, but in in this day and age, this looks like it wants to be a Python, Ruby, or Perl script, perhaps with a C module for speed if you are serious about performance... assuming what you need cannot easily be done in just shell (maybe with a bit of Awk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Burhan Khalid and @hobbs. It seems that the popen does not use bash for piping. To use bash, I modified the popen line to:

```
FILE* pipe = popen("exec bash -c 'cp files/file{100..102}.txt filesCopy'", "r");
```

The expansion is working correctly now.